# Скачать архив с удаленного сервера ubuntu через ssh консоль

Tags: linux, ubuntu

На удаленном сервере с делал архив.

```
app-name.tar.gz
```

Я хочу скачать его себе на локальную машину

```
scp root@85.143.59.249:home/backend/app-name.tar.gz /downloads
```

В консоли получаю сообщение

```
app-name.tar.gz                                             100%   19MB  19.4MB/s   00:00
```

Но в папке загрузки файл не появился. Как скачать мой архив себе на локальную машину?

Comment: Попробуйте перед home поставить слеш корневого каталога `scp root@85.143.59.249:/home/backend/app-name.tar.gz /downloads`

Comment: @PotroNik не помогло, показывает что файл скачался

Comment: А что возвращает `du -h /downloads`?

Comment: Из-под суперпользователя?! Ой-ой. Смотрите вывод `ls -l /downloads`.

Comment: Вы скачали этот файл и сохранили его под именем /downloads. На основании этого можете поразмыслить самостоятельно, почему работа под рутом — плохая идея, и крайне плохая идея для того, кто ещё не очень понимает, что́ он делает.

Comment: А ещё можно качнуть как `scp root@85.143.59.249:home/backend/app-name.tar.gz /etc/fstab`. Будет очень весело, особенно после перезагрузки. P.S. Присоединяюсь ко всем кто писал про рута.